# How to Augument commonjs module from requiring code?

Tags: javascript, prototype, commonjs

I am wondering how I can augument a commonjs module from another module that requires it.

Let's assume that I have three files, two commonjs modules as below:

---

**my-example-module.js**

```
function MyExampleModule(){}

MyExampleModule.prototype = {

    bindings: {
        some: 'random',
        prop: 'values'
    }

}

module.exports = MyExampleModule;
```

---

*another-example-module.js*

```
var MyExampleModule = require('./my-example-module');

function AnotherExampleModule(){}

AnotherExampleModule.prototype = {

    getMyExampleModuleBindings: function(){
        var module = new MyExampleModule();
        return module.bindings;
    }

}

module.exports = AnotherExampleModule;
```

---

*app.js*

```
var MyExampleModule = require('./my-example-module');
var AnotherExampleModule = require('./another-example-module');

//modify?!?

var anotherExampleModule = new AnotherExampleModule();
console.log(anotherExampleModule.getMyExampleModuleBindings());
```

So what I want to do is have `//modify?!?` be some kind of code that will alter the original `MyExampleModule` prototype so when anything else attempts to `require` MyExampleModule it will get the modified version.

A concrete question would be - what should I replace `//modify?!?` with so  I get logged out the the console with the assumption that my-example-module.js is read only.

```
{
    some: 'random',
    prop: 'values',
    added: 'binding'
}
```

Comment: 1st. That is platform dependand, so add the relevant tag (could be nodejs, but could be other implementation). 2nd. Basically, you can't - But if you insist on it you'd have to override `require` and even than your app.js won't do that since `//modify?!?` will be too late.

Comment: @Amit I didn't add the platform tag as for my purposes this would be run through browserify and used in the browser, but I thought the same idea would apply anywhere you can use commonjs (and figured that browserify wasn't relevant here hence didn't tag it).

Comment: Just to explain my statement about `//modify?!?` being too late, in your case it might not be too late, but a general approach will be since `require()` is supposed to execute the code inside the module synchronously. If that code relies on the modification, it's too late. You should use [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to achieve your task.

Comment: @Hailwood what is my answer missing?

Comment: @nils Nothing, I just haven't had a chance to test it with browserify yet :) Once I have If it works I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in nodejs/iojs, this is pretty simple. When node imports a CommonJS module (let's call it `A`), it creates an internal object.

When another module (`B`) wants to load the same module (`A`), it just gets the reference to that internal object. So if you change something on `MyExampleModule` in `app.js` it is also applied to the `MyExampleModule` in `another-example-module.js`:

*app.js*

```
var MyExampleModule = require('./my-example-module');
var AnotherExampleModule = require('./another-example-module');

//modify:

MyExampleModule.prototype.bindings = {
    some: 'random',
    prop: 'values',
    added: 'binding'
};

var anotherExampleModule = new AnotherExampleModule();
console.log(anotherExampleModule.getMyExampleModuleBindings());
```

Since you create a new instance of `MyExampleModule` in `another-example-module.js` *after* you call `MyExampleModule.prototype.bindings = {...}` in `app.js`, the new instance will already be created with the modified `.prototype`.

While I haven't tested this in browserify, it certainly works in webpacks implementation of CommonJS as well.

Check out the working example on runnable (*app.js* is called *server.js*):
http://code.runnable.com/VZPdN5k65gE5vUIz